# how to get the number of minutes from a specific time up to the current time using java.util.Date?

Tags: java

so i have this homework and this is the given problem:

Per-minute charging offers at 75 cents a minute from 5:01 am to 5:00 pm, and 90 cents a minute from 5:01 pm to 5:00 am.

this is my code:

```
double charge = 0;

Date date = new Date();

if(date.getHours() >= 5 && date.getHours() <= 17)
{
    charge += 0.75 * date.getMinutes();
    System.out.println(charge);
}
else
{
    charge += 0.9 * date.getMinutes();
    System.out.println(charge);
}
```

my problem is that the date.getMinutes() only gets the current minute of the current hours,
it supposed to be the number of minutes from 5:01am up to the current time and the else statement likewise. any idea guys? thx alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for this you can do

```
totalHours = date.getHours() - 5;
totalMinutes = (totalHours * 60) + date.getMinutes();
```

Similarly, you could write it for the other part.

As it has been pointed out that the above methods have been deprecated, here is how you can do it with the `Calendar`

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendat.setTime(date);

if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 5 && calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 17)
{
    int totalHours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 5;
    int totalMinutes = (totalHours * 60) + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

else
{
    totalHours = 24 - calendar.get(HOUR_OF_DAY) + 5;
    totalMinutes = (totalHours * 60) - (60 - calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}
```

Comment: Date.getMinutes() is deprecated, better use the Calendar class

Comment: As a matter of fact even date.getHours() is deprecated. I was merely explaining the logic :)

Comment: @noMad would you explain this totalHours = date.getHours() - 5?thx

Comment: Ill tell you using the `calendar` cause that's what you need to use now. `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` would return the current hour in the 24 hour format. Hence if you subtract that from 5 (which is essentially 5am) you would have the total hours from 5am till current.

Comment: so how will i code that one or include that in my existing code?

Comment: yaay its working! but how about if its between 5pm and 5am, this should be in my else statement.

Comment: my time format is in 12hours format. so if i use the same logic in my else statement it will come up to a logic error.